# run time initialization of array in java

Tags: java, arrays

i cant understand why i am getting error in the initialization of array in main. i decleared a variable t and took its value from the keyboard. but when i try to initialize an array n[ ] with size t, it shows an error.plz help

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class smallfac
{
    static BigInteger fac(BigInteger x)
    {
        BigInteger z;
        if(x.equals(new BigInteger("1")))
            return x;
        else
        {
            z=x.multiply(fac(x.subtract(new BigInteger("1"))));
            return(z);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(in);
        try{
            int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }catch(IOException e){}
        int[] n=new int[t];
        for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                n[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            }catch(IOException e){}
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
        {
            int x=n[i];
            BigInteger p = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(x));
            p=smallfac.fac(p);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few problems:

```
try{
    int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}catch(IOException e){}

int[] n=new int[t];
```

Two problems there:

1. `t` is only declared within the `try` block. It's out-of-scope outside that block. Thus, a compile-time error trying to use `t` on the last line above.
2. Even if you fix that by declaring `t` outside the block and then initializing it inside the block, the compiler can't be sure that `t` has a value as of the last line above. An exception may have been thrown instead. So that's an error (a compile-time error).

The later, a third issue (at least):

```
for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
{
    try
    {
        n[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }catch(IOException e){}
}
```

This is a logic error. If you try to use `n[i]` in your later loop, you have no idea whether `n[i]` has been actually initialized, because you've hidden your exception. For all you know, there was an I/O exception initializing `n[2]` and so `n[2]` keeps the default `null` value. If you try to use it later without checking for that, you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

It's a **really bad idea** to catch and ignore exceptions, particularly doing it repeatedly for specific lines of code like that.

Here's a minimal-changes reworking of that `main`:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    // Put all the code in one try block
    try {
        InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(in);
        int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[] n=new int[t];
        for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
        {
            n[i]=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++)
        {
            int x=n[i];
            BigInteger p = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(x));
            p=smallfac.fac(p);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        // Report the error here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a scoping issue. You declare `int t` inside of the `try` block, but then attempt to use the value of `t` after it, and that's not possible; `t` is only visible inside of the `try`.

Comment: One of several problems. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`int[] n=new int[t];` <- here `t` must be a defined in scope. you can change it to:

```
        int t = 0;//or some default value
        try{
            t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }catch(IOException e){}
        int[] n=new int[t];
```

Comment: `t` must exists, but needs not be constant.

Answer (score 0):

`t` is defined inside **try-block**. thus its **scope** is `limited to try block`. you can't access it outside try block. define it outside try, such that your array initialization can access it